# cannot convert from Iterable<Iterable<Integer>> to int[][]

Tags: xtend

When I print

`(0..1).map[i | (0..1).map[j | j]]`

I get `[[0, 1], [0, 1]]` as output.

But when I want to assign it to a 2d `int` array

`val int[][] mat = (1..2).map[i | (1..2).map[j | i * j]]`

I get the error message

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterable<Iterable> to int[][]

How can I convert to `int[][]` or what is the better way to initialize the 2d array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling primitives and arrays often feels a bit weird in Xtend, but to my surprise there is actually a quite simple solution using the `com.google.common.primitives.Ints` class from Guava:

```
val int[][] intArr = (0 .. 1).map[Ints.toArray((0 .. 1).toList)]
```

This relies on Xtend's automatic conversion between arrays and list, which also works with multidimensional arrays - and as in this case it apparently can convert `Iterable<int[]>` to `int[][]`.

If you only want to create a small, constant `int[][]` array, then you could also use list literals instead:

```
val int[][] intArr = #[#[0, 1], #[0, 1]]
```

If you only want to create an empty `int[][]` array, you can just use `newIntArrayOfSize(s1, s2)`:

```
val int[][] emptyIntArr  = newIntArrayOfSize(2, 2)
```